# Doxygen latex output: Chapters, sections and subsections numbering

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I'm using **doxygen** with **markdown** files to produce pdf files via the LaTeX output.
Files are organized in a hierarchical way using `@subpage` tags.
The "Title 1" levels of each Markdown files are referred as "Chapter" or "Section" in LaTeX files according to the level of Markdown files in the hierarchy. The PDF output of these "Chapter" and "Section" are numbered. OK until here.

But the PDF output misses the numbering of subsections and paragraphs and lower items. By parsing the LaTeX files, I can see asterisks (`*`) at these items like `\subsection*{My Section}`.

My questions:

1. How to tell Doxygen not to add these asterisks so I can have a numbering like "1.1", "1.1.1" and so on?
2. by removing the asterisks, wouldn't I have a growing TOC? How can I limit the deepness of the resulting TOC?
3. The "Chapter" numbering is quite strange (Chapter XX \r\n Blabla). How do you force the "XX Blabla" format?

**Some precisions:**

Doxygen version: **1.8.14**

Markdown files are organized like this:

```
FILES                 LaTex result
/root_folder
+---file1.md      ->  \chapter{My title 1}\label{my_title_1}\Hypertarget{my_title_1}
+---file1.1.md    ->  \section{My title 1.1}\label{my_title_1_1}\Hypertarget{my_title_1_1}
+---file1.2.md    ->  \section{My title 1.2}\label{my_title_1_2}\Hypertarget{my_title_1_2}
+---file2.md      ->  \chapter{My title 2}\label{my_title_2}\Hypertarget{my_title_2}
+---file2.1.md    ->  \section{My title 2.1}\label{my_title_2_1}\Hypertarget{my_title_2_1}
+---file2.2.md    ->  \section{My title 2.2}\label{my_title_2_2}\Hypertarget{my_title_2_2}
+---doxyfile
```

- Each md file **starts with a Title1 tag**: # My title XX {#my_title_xx}
- The content of each md file continues with Title2, Title3... (## Sub title, ### Sub title, ...)
- A md file may refer to subpages (e.g. file1.md refers to file1.1.md and file1.2.md).

**What I get:**

- Title1 tags are converted as chapter or section according to the place in the hierarchy. They are numbered (i.e. without "*") => **OK**.
- Title2, 3.. tags of each file are converted as subsection or subsubsection according to the place in the hierarchy They are **un**numbered (i.e. with "*") and absent from the TOC => **KO**.

Hope these information are clear ;)
Maybe there is another way to make structured LaTex/PDF output from md files...

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you give an example of places where you would like not to have the asterisk? Regarding point 3) you could probably define your own chapter  style.

Comment: It does shine a bit of light on the problem, but could you (at least ) add the file1.md and file1.1.md so we are sure we looking at the same problem (I did some small edits as I think not all titles were correct).